# Failed to obtain magnetic field sensor on Pixel 2 despite it exists on sensor list

Tags: java, android, sensormanager

I tried to get magnetic field sensor with the following code, permission for fine location access has obtained:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
magneticSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
```

I test my app with Google pixel 2 and the sensorManager is null as result, same when replaced sensor type with TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD_UNCALIBRATED.

However, when I get list of sensors on my Pixel 2 with the following code:

```
List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```

I see "hall effect sensor" in the list, which I believe is the magnetic field sensor, the description of the sensor object is as follow:

```
{Sensor name="AK8789 Hall Effect", vendor="AKM", version=1, type=33171016, maxRange=1.0, resolution=1.0, power=0.001, minDelay=0}
```

Edit: tested my devices with a compass app and proved the magnetic sensor is probably defected. So if the sensor is defected, the code above return null. I also tested the code with another pixel device and found the sensor for compass is called magnetometer, not hall effect sensor

Comment: Googling for _android sensors hall effect_ suggests that such a sensor is _"used to lock/disable the screen in smart phones whenever a flip cover, equipped with magnets, touches the screen"_. That seems different from a geomagnetic field sensor, which is what you appear to be looking for.

Comment: Probably your Pixel  magnetic sensor is defected. I had phone with magnetic field sensor and then one day the magnetic field just disappears.

Comment: @HoanNguyen you are right. I tested my device with compass app and proved the sensor is probably defected. So if the sensor is defected the code above return null instead

Comment: The magnetometer sensor seems to have failed on my Google Pixel 2 as well. The phone was left on the desk unused for about 3 months and the sensor failed during that time. As a result, I don't get data for `TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` or `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` (which depends on magnetometer).